# Binding redux state to an object

Tags: javascript, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

Is there an established way to bind a redux state to an object?

I want to do something like this:

```
MyApi.setStore(myReduxStore, 'stateVar')
```

I've played with passing various get/set actions and store listeners but it's a mess.

```
MyApi.getState = () => store.dispatch(getAction())
MyApi.setState = (state) => store.dispatch(setAction(state))
let currentState
store.subscribe(() => {
  let previousState = currentState
  currentState = store.getState().stateVar
  if(previousState !== currentState) {
    MyApi.stateListener(currentState)
  }
})
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Redux state is the object already...

Comment: My API does some async stuff. I want it to expose it's state to redux, so it can be picked up in various react components.

Comment: Knowing that every reducer returns new state, you could  create the  reducer that will return state from your API.

Answer (score 0):

The way to do api calls in redux is to use a middleware like [redux-thunk](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk) or [redux-saga](https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga). That way you separate the api call from redux and just dispatch an action when the result is ready.

Example of an API call from redux-saga readme:

```
import { call, put, takeEvery, takeLatest } from 'redux-saga/effects'
import Api from '...'

// worker Saga: will be fired on USER_FETCH_REQUESTED actions
function* fetchUser(action) {
   try {
      const user = yield call(Api.fetchUser, action.payload.userId);
      yield put({type: "USER_FETCH_SUCCEEDED", user: user});
   } catch (e) {
      yield put({type: "USER_FETCH_FAILED", message: e.message});
   }
}

/*
  Starts fetchUser on each dispatched `USER_FETCH_REQUESTED` action.
  Allows concurrent fetches of user.
*/
function* mySaga() {
  yield takeEvery("USER_FETCH_REQUESTED", fetchUser);
}

/*
  Alternatively you may use takeLatest.

  Does not allow concurrent fetches of user. If "USER_FETCH_REQUESTED" gets
  dispatched while a fetch is already pending, that pending fetch is cancelled
  and only the latest one will be run.
*/
function* mySaga() {
  yield takeLatest("USER_FETCH_REQUESTED", fetchUser);
}

export default mySaga;
```

Then your reducer will just set loading state to true on "USER_FETCH_REQUESTED", update the state on "USER_FETCH_SUCCEEDED" and set some error state on "USER_FETCH_FAILED".

Comment: Thanks. I've used redux-thunk for a variety of things which involved mapping at least one action to each api method. If the api was configured to be aware of state perhaps some of this could be reduced.

Comment: I've not used thunk but at least with sagas, you end up with a lot of boilerplate code. I've been thinking of writing a helper function that would just do:
`createApiHandler("USER_FETCH_REQUESTED", Api.fetchUser , "USER_FETCH_SUCCEEDED", "USER_FETCH_FAILED")`